# Salesforce formula field on Activity object to capture when the Activity was completed

Tags: formula, formula-field, administration

I have created one field Activity completed date (formula field) to calculate the Activity start date and when user checks checkbox as true  needs to know the date of Activity completed date.
So my formula is Activity completed date = IF(Completed_Meeting__c = true, TODAY(), null). It works well but whenever the user loads the records it's calculating again and putting today's date even though the user checked the checkbox yesterday and no action taken on that record.

I cannot use the ISCHANGED function in formulas, and for a simple requirement I don't want to go with Flow.

Any suggestions please? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Formula fields never only calculate the value once. The "recalculates every time a user loads the page" bit is exactly what formula fields are meant to do.

If you want to capture a particular moment in time, then you need to use a normal (non-formula) field. You would populate that field using a trigger or a record-triggered (before save) flow.

Comment: Sure thanks,  I thought for this  simple requirement  I can tweak formula a bit to avoid flow but if we don't have option I will create flow